# Changing a security template setting in windows

Tags: windows, windows-xp, security

I'm trying to learn about windows security templates on xp. In my example, I want to change a setting on a windows xp machine.  I generate the sdb and .ini file then apply it using

`cmd /c echo y | secedit /configure /db "Test.sdb" /cfg "Test.inf" /overwrite /verbose`

Will this actually change the setting or only allow me to change the setting?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will import the security template specified in Test.inf into the database Test.sdb and apply it to the system.